# How to insert a variable in spss?

Tags: spss

I wanted to inserted a variable in the middle of my data file through syntax, But could not find the way to do this, do anybody know this how to do?

Regards,

Ramamoorthy.

Comment: Are you planning on doing so with a programming language like C# ?

Comment: Could you be specific? Do you want this variable to be calculated from existing variables? Is it from a keyed table? Is it blank? Does it have a constant value? There are many ways to do this depending on your specifics.

Comment: Say for example, if i have variables x and y i would like to compute(insert) a variable called 'z' between x and y with any value through syntax. so that the order of my variables would seems like x z y.

Answer (score 1):

```
 MATCH FILES FILE=* /KEEP=var1 var2 var3 .
 execute.
```

Using this syntax you can order the variables in the way you want.